# Using Lerna with unpublished packages

Tags: lerna

I'm trying to set up my monorepo with Lerna. The plan is to refactor an existing project by pulling chunks of code out which should be their own packages. I've run `lerna init`, and my current setup looks like this:

```
project/
  packages/
    new-refactored-package/
      package.json
    prior-existing-project/
      package.json
        { "dependencies" : { "new-refactored-package" : "latest" } }
  package.json
    {
      "devDependencies": {
        "lerna": "^2.0.0-rc.5"
      }
    }
  lerna.json
    {
      "lerna": "2.0.0-rc.5",
      "packages": [
        "packages/*"
      ],
      "version": "0.0.0"
    }
```

My understanding was that `lerna bootstrap` at this point is supposed to locate `package1` in the project and symlink it to `prior-existing-project`'s `/node_modules/new-refactored-package/`. From [lerna's readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna#bootstrap):

> Bootstrap the packages in the current Lerna repo. Installs all of their dependencies and links any cross-dependencies.
>
> When run, this command will:
>
> - npm install all external dependencies of each package.
> - **Symlink together all Lerna packages that are dependencies of each other.**
> - npm prepublish all bootstrapped packages.

However, when I run it, lerna attempts instead to `npm install new-refactored-package`:

> npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/new-refactored-package

Am I misunderstanding? Do I first have to publish the depended-upon packages to `npm`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem too! Documentation is misleading about unpublished packages and linking. I hope somebody can help us here.

Answer (score 18):

## Requirements

For `lerna` to symlink a local package when running [`lerna bootstrap`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap#readme) the local package must have a `name` *and* `version` that matches. Whenever `lerna` cannot match a dependency to a local package, it'll try to install it from the registry.

So ensure that the dependency package has a version that can be matched by the [semver](https://semver.npmjs.com/) version in the dependant.

## Example

```
{

  name: "@my-name/dependency",
  version: "1.2.0"
}
```

```
{
  name: "@my-name/dependant",
  dependencies: {
    "@my-name/dependency": "<VERSION>"
  }
}
```

`@my-name/dependency` will be symlinked when `VERSION` is `1.2.0`, `^1.0.0`, `1.X.X`, or `*`. However when using ranges that does not match the local package, like `1.0.0` or `^0.0.0`, it will try to resolve it in the npm registry and will show the error like 
`404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@my-name%2fdependency - Not found`.

## `latest`

In the actual scenario that is explained in the question, the actual issue is that the version is specified as `latest` and while it's easy to think that `latest` is a generic term for *the latest version available*, it's actually a [`npm-dist-tag`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) which is applied by default to all new releases.

If you look at packages like [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) (click *versions*), you can see that other than the `latest`, they also deploy releases with tags `next`, `canary` and `unstable`.

Your unpublished package does not have *any* tags, as they are applied on publication, and so `latest` will not match, meaning `lerna` will try to resolve it remotely, failing with `404`.

This is noted as one of the *gotchas* in the [*Notes*](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/v3.13.1/commands/bootstrap#notes) of the documentation for the `bootstrap` command.

> - When a dependency version in a package is not satisfied by a package of the same name in the repo, it will be `npm install`ed (or `yarn`ed) like normal.
> - **Dist-tags, like `latest`, do not satisfy [semver](https://semver.npmjs.com/) ranges.**
> - Circular dependencies result in circular symlinks which *may* impact your editor/IDE.

## Solution

If you want to match *whatever version that is available*, the recommended path would be to set the version to `"*"`. This will match any version and will thus always use the local version, given that the local package has a specified `version` field.

```
{ 
  "dependencies": { 
    "new-refactored-package" : "*"
  }
}
```

> `alpha`, `rc` or `beta`
>
> Even `*` will *not* match versions that are marked as pre-release, so if you give your local package a version like `0.0.1-alpha.0`, or `1.0.0-rc.3`, it will also not be locally symlinked

## `private: true`

While it does not affect `lerna bootstrap`, it's worth mentioning that packages that you do not want to be published should always have `private: true;`. This will ensure that [`lerna publish`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/publish#readme) does not publish it.

Comment: I don't get why `npm i my-local-package@1.0.0` gives me this error then, while adding it manually to `package.json` works.

Comment: @EricBurel You can't install a local package with `npm`. Adding it to the package.json and then running `lerna bootstrap` can work, if the package is available locally. But npm does not support local packages and does not benefit from lernas functionalities. To add packages that are either remote (published packages) or local (in the lerna workspace), you can use `lerna add my-local-package@1.0.0 packages/app-to-install-in` https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/add

Comment: @oBusk Does this mean that once I add a local package as a dependency, I would not be able to run `npm install` or `npm uninstall <some other dependency>` anymore as hey will fail with `npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<My-Lerna Local Dependency> - Not found`

Comment: @oBusk Looks like what running `npm uninstall` in the repo will run into issues as per https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1229 :(

Answer (score 7):

`lerna bootstrap` will symlink packages instead of install if they are **available**.

In your case, I think lerna cannot find the correct `version` or `name` of the package.

Here is what I did in my project ...

```
project
- packages/
    - a_pkg
        - package.json {
            "name": "@scope/a_pkg",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "private": true
            /// opt out
        }
    - b_pkg
        - package.json {
            "name": "@scope/b_pkg",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "private": true,
            "dependencies": {
              "@scope/a_pkg": "^0"
            },
            /// opt out
        }
- package.json
- lerna.json {
    "packages": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    /// opt out
}
```

Comment: Are the private and version keys critical?

Comment: The version is required in the dependency (`a_pkg`) so that lerna can assure the correct version. The dependant (`b_pkg`) does not technically require a version for bootstrap to work in this scenario. 
The `private: true` has effect primarily on `lerna publish` as to not try to publish the package to NPM. It is not needed for bootstrap to work.

Answer (score 1):

`lerna bootstrap` will check the package version you specified in `package.json` or `package-lock.json`.

Since you have not published your work, I would give a try to use `--force-local` on the `bootstrap` command.

`lerna bootstrap --force-local`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the dependencies using "lerna add <DEPENDENCY_NAME>" command instead of adding the dependencies manually. This will automatically add the local version(if available)

Answer (score -2):

The package name in package.json has to match the folder name in /packages folder.

(Essentially what @kp_ping said)

Comment: The folder does not need to match the package name. The dependency must have the correct name and must have a `version` that can be matched.