# How to configure the parent lib (in TS) to be linked from its examples?

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, lerna, logary

I would like to use a parent NPM package from inside a subfolder, as part of the development process. Let's call **my library** "logary".

Structure:

```
.
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
|- src
 |- ... all the source code
|- dist
 |- ... compiled TS as .js, .js.map and .d.ts
|- examples
 |- with-nextjs
  |- package.json
  |- tsconfig.json
```

The library is written in TypeScript and so is the example. The parent compiles with `outDir: ./dist` in `tsconfig.json`. I have multiple entry points (one for the main lib, one for each peer dependency as for example: `import withLogary from 'logary/plugins/nextjs'`.

I would like to be able to write `import Logary from 'logary';` inside `./examples/with-nextjs` and have `Logary`, the constructor, have types attached to it be fully "resolvable" by the TypeScript compiler. I want changes in `.` to be reflected when `./examples/with-nextjs` is reloaded.

It's not a monorepo (in the common sense). I've tried `yarn link` in `.` and then `yarn link logary` inside `./examples/with-nextjs`, which doesn't seem to solve it (cannot import module). Furthermore, as I have bumped the version in `.` to `6.0.0`, as I `yarn install` inside `./examples/with-nextjs`, yarn complains that version is not published to npmjs.com and asks me to select a previous version, which it then downloads.

I know there's [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) ("Splitting up large codebases into separate independently versioned packages is extremely useful for code sharing." — this is a tiny code-base and only has a single package, I just want to reference it in a single direction from an example) and [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) ("It allows you to setup multiple packages in such a way that you only need to run yarn install once to install all of them in a single pass." — which is not my aim)

I'm not interested in adding any special config (like `paths`) to `tsconfig.json` in `./examples/with-nextjs` because then it's not just to copy the example to as your own app.

**➡ How do I best structure a TypeScript library project with multiple peer dependencies and with an examples folder?**

Maybe related?

- [Use yarn workspaces and typescript's project references to reference another package subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518870/use-yarn-workspaces-and-typescripts-project-references-to-reference-another-pac) — use `exports` in package.json to solve the `logary/plugins/nextjs` problem (I'm happy doing that, but I can't get the parent project properly linked with peers correctly installed, so just `import Logary from 'logary'` in the examples uses the old published version, despite me having run `yarn link`)
- [Peer Dependencies In A Monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027193/peer-dependencies-in-a-monorepo) — this is probably a good solution to the peer dependencies problem (e.g. with https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external)
- [Using Lerna with unpublished packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491525/using-lerna-with-unpublished-packages) — has a similar question, but doesn't ask about consume-only app packages like my `with-nextjs`. Also, my root is at `.` not at `packages/logary`; but maybe I must conform?
- Using `composite: true` in tsconfig.json in `.` and also `references` in the child project's `tsconfig.json` changes how the `outDir` works; it adds the `src/` folder as prefix to all output paths, which is not what I want