# How do I properly create a new package in lerna monorepo?

Tags: npm, monorepo, lerna

I inherited a monorepo with a `packages` folder that has every existing package. I want to add a `main` package that is required by my `panel` package. `panel` already exists at version `0.34.0`. Seeing as I merge to my repo without publishing a new version all the time, I want to create `main` at `0.34.0`.

I tried going into `packages/main` but doing `npx lerna publish` only wants me to do `0.34.1` so I am worried if I try to do custom `0.34.0` I will break something. I tried `npx lerna boostrap` but it even says it goes to `root` doesn't ask for me to do anything in regards to brand new package in existing project.

Do I need to create the package and bump my whole monorepo to `0.34.1` via publish to then let any existing package use it?

I use symlinks locally, but when I go to make a PR, my CI will run `yarn install` which (I don't think) would find the packages when reviewing the `package.json`s. Therefore, I don't think [Using Lerna with unpublished packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491525/using-lerna-with-unpublished-packages) applies here? I think I need to actually publish a version that can be referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going into the new `main` folder and typing `npm publish` - and just skipping lerna, is what worked. Found that out here: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1691.

Everything went where I expected and then I could just manually update package.json files as needed that are using the new package.